# nokogiri parsing error

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse an xml document that comes from a client machine. I'm using ruby 1.8.7 and nokogiri.
I'm getting an error: "Error in nokogiri parsing  PCDATA invalid Char value 3" but I can't understand the message
The string that's causing an issue is : Devd\003\002\b\017.exe
How can I fix this or just skip this entry (it's causing the parsing to go directly to the rescue block)
Thanks!

Comment: How do you get the xml document to be parsed into memory?

Comment: by calling : reader  = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(xml)

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you would include a sample of XML that causes this error directly, and described the character encoding for your file.

Comment: Here it is, problem is I get this in the console, so it has the console encoding, any tip on how I could get the raw xml?   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><list><a><t>BeatHarness v2.5 Patch by M0usAKa</a></tsp><tsp><a>Devd\003\002\b\017.exe</a></tsp></list>

Comment: If you’re just typing (or pasting) it into the console, it’s being treated as a string literal so `\003` is interpreted as being the byte with value 3, which isn’t a valid character, rather than the string `\003`. Try escaping the slash with `\\003` or putting the xml in a file and using `File.read`.